# terminology about ring/algebra in abstract algebra and measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, abstract-algebra

Both in abstract algebra and measure theory is there term ring/algebra, but their definition are different and we can not deduce one from the other, the only requirement in definition they share is that they be closed under two operations: addition and multiplication in abstract algebra while difference and union in measure theory. Why we use the same term for these two different notions in two different branches of mathematics? Is there any connection between them? Thanks!

To be more specific, my intention is to compare "ring in measure theory" with "ring in abstract algebra", not "ring" with "algebra". I use notation "ring/algebra" in the post because the term algebra has the same situation, that is, compare "algebra in measure theory" with "algebra in abstract algebra".

Comment: Why *not* use the same term?

Comment: It's been a while since I read it, but doesn' Halmos' *Measure Theory* book have some brief discussion of this?

Comment: I found my question in Ex.(4), page 22 of Halmos' Measure Theory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [ring of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) is a ring(usual definition) with the operations intersection(multiplication) and symmetric difference(addition). A [sigma ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_ring) is a special kind of a ring of sets. Now a [sigma algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) <strike>(which would possibly more appropriately be called sigma field) is a sigma ring where every element has a complement (multiplicative inverse)</strike> is a sigma ring with unity (equivalent to every element has a complement),thus it is a Boolean algebra with respect to intersection and union, and a Boolean ring with respect to intersection and symmetric difference. Every Boolean ring is an algebra over $\mathbb F_2$(thank you Mark Meckes for the correction). I hope this connection is enough to justify the use of these terms.

Comment: Thank you but, to be more specific, my intention is to compare "ring in measure theory" with "ring in abstract algebra", not "ring" with "algebra". I use notation "ring/algebra" in the post because the term algebra has the same situation, that is, compare "algebra in measure theory" with "algebra in abstract algebra". 

Comment: zzzhhh, I think you should read both Gjergji and Pete's answers more closely.

Comment: The complement of a set is not a multiplicative inverse; the product is the empty set, which is the additive identity.  So a field/algebra of sets is not a field in the sense of abstract algebra.  On the other hand, an algebra of sets is an algebra in the sense of abstract algebra: it is a ring as you explained, and also a vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ of 2 elements, which makes it an $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra.  This is why I personally prefer the terminology "sigma algebra" over "sigma field".

Answer (score 16):

There is a mathematical relationship between the two concepts: given an algebra of sets, one can define a commutative ring by taking addition to be symmetric difference and multiplication to be intersection.  This ring is a **Boolean ring**, i.e., $x^2 = x$ for all elements $x$.  Conversely, the Stone Representation Theorem says that every Boolean ring can be viewed as the ring associated to some algebra of sets.  See e.g. Section 4.5

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)

for more detailed statements and proofs.

Comment: Thank you but, to be more specific, my intention is to compare "ring in measure theory" with "ring in abstract algebra", not "ring" with "algebra". I use notation "ring/algebra" in the post because the term algebra has the same situation, that is, compare "algebra in measure theory" with "algebra in abstract algebra".


Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a ring is an algebra over the integers.